# MySQL is refusing to save in UTF-8

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to save in MySQL DBMS in utf-8 , but it doesn't accept and give me Ø§Ø­ÙØ¯ Ø¬ÙØ§Ù  instead , i searched about this problem in many different references and i found the configuration code of integrating utf-8 from Java , i did it but it gives me the same result , here is my code cut it from my DB class:

```
private static final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
private static final String dbName = "m_e_clinic";
private static final String collation = "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";
private static final String dbUserName = "root";
private static final String dbPassword = "root";

Connection connection = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");         
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Class doesn't exist");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL+dbName+colVal, dbUserName, dbPassword);
        return connection;
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

I also configure my DB itself and made the collation utf8-general-ci , but no acceptable result is given.

Comment: Try useUnicode=yes instead of useUnicode=true

Comment: Does it returns proper connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it , the problem was in my Servlet , i just add this line :

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this the issue could be utf-8 instead of UTF-8:

```
useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Check this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Comment: I tried all , but the same result ( Connection is established ) but save in random character form.

Comment: I solved it , the problem was in my Servlet , i just edit this line :
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
Thanks a lot.